# multiple outcomes - how to deal with dependency in meta-analysis

Tags: r, meta-analysis, independence, meta-regression

I have been studying the paper - **Handling Complex Meta-analytic Data Structures Using Robust Variance Estimates: a Tutorial in R**. I would like to ask if there is a problem in dividing a dependent dataset into subcomponents (e.g. language and memory) when conducting a meta-analysis whilst acknowledging the dependencies within the subcomponents, the higher dependency of a study which measures both language and memory would be missed. Would that be problematic? I see this done a lot in the literature, where studies focus only on one or two areas of the set of correlations provided in a paper, but I am not sure if that is ok given the dependencies.